# How to make mean shift clustering? Any code c# available with or without emgu?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I need to know how to make mean shift clustering, I'm searching for any implementation using emgu library or without it.
I also want to know what is the difference between k-mean and mean shift and other kind of shifts?

Comment: Mean shift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831813/image-segmentation-using-mean-shift-explained/4835340#4835340

Comment: K-Means example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165867/create-a-summary-description-of-a-schedule-given-a-list-of-shifts/3251229#3251229

Comment: this link is for mean shift segmentation not clustering .

Comment: It's the same algorithm used for lightly different purposes. See for example http://www.sci.utah.edu/~fletcher/CS7960/homeworks/hw3.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-Means is a clustering algorithm which combines into groups objects in metric space. Meanshift is a [procedure for locating the maxima of a density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift), which is used for example for tracking objects on the scene.

Comment: so is there any implementation for meanshift in c# , or steps to iplement it ?

Comment: Implementation of meanshift is included to OpenCV library. EmguCv is a binding to C#. Doesn't it contain meanshift interface?

Comment: ok, what i've wrote about using meanshift is related to camshift.